# Next, accept, etc automatica al Instalar .msi desde powerShell

Tags: powershell

No he usado mucho PowerShell pero me encuentro en la necesidad de instalar una archivo .msi desde powerShell y tengo el siguiente comando.

`Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait '/i "C:..."'`

Esto lo que hace es abrir la interfaz de instalación respectiva, para dar next, next, accept... etc, yo lo que busco es la manera de que todo ese next, next, se haga de manera automática.

Primero que todo, es posible hacerlo de está manera? Segundo como se haría?

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me pueda brindar, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si alguien más le pasó lo mismo, lo resolví de la siguiente manera

`Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/i C:\Installers\file.msi /q'`